# How to explain this formally?

Tags: general-topology

This is an exercise of my homework:

> > Let $K\subset A\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ such that $N\in\mathbb{N}^*$, $K$ is compact and $A$ is open. Show that there is an $K_1$ compact such that $K\subset {K_1}^o \subset K_1 \subset A$

(Where ${K_1}^o$ is the set of interior points of $K_1$)

My strategy is show that there is a closed set $F$ in $A$ containing $K$, but how to do this? In $\mathbb{R}$ this is simple, but how to do in $\mathbb{R}^N$? The idea is that because A is open and K is compact we have (interior) points of A outside of K but how to use this to find $F$?

Comment: A positive integer @BrianM.Scott (sorry)

Comment: Sorry, is a positive integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: For each $x\in K$ there is an $\epsilon_x>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon_x)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}B(x,\epsilon_x)\subseteq A$. Each of the sets $\operatorname{cl}B(x,\epsilon_x)$ is closed and bounded in $\Bbb R^N$, so it’s compact. Let $\mathscr{U}=\{B(x,\epsilon_x):x\in K\}$; $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $K$. Now use the fact that $K$ is compact.

Here $B(x,\epsilon)$ is the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centred at $x$ in the usual Euclidean metric.

Comment: How you garantee that $cl B(x,\varepsilon_x)\subset A$?

Comment: @Felipe: Metric spaces are regular.

Comment: Right!! Using that i will get a countable open cover X of K in A such that each closure is in A and the interior countains K? :D (this set are closed because is a finite union of closed sets)

Comment: @Felipe: You’ll get a **finite** open cover, but I think that *countable* was just a typo, since you had it right in the parenthesis. Yep; that’s what happens.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Is there an issue if $\partial K\cap\partial A\ne\emptyset$? For example, if $K$ is the closed unit sphere, and $A=\{x=(x_1,\dots,x_N): |x_i|<1, 1\le i\le N\}$.

Comment: @Tim: That can’t happen.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I edited my comment. Don't my $A$ and $K$ have intersecting boundaries?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh wait, I've got it. In that case, $K$ is not contained in $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $d=\inf\{\text d(a,b):a\in K, b\in \partial A\}$. Let $K_1=\left\{x\in A : \text d(x,K)\le \frac d2\right\}$.  I believe that should work.

Comment: $A$ might be all of $\Bbb R^N$.

Comment: Good point, if $A=\Bbb R^N$, $K\subseteq B(0,M)$ for some $M>0$.

Comment: Here $K\not\subset K_1$

Comment: OK, I edited it.

Comment: Thanks, but can you write this without use the idea of distance of a point to a set?

Comment: If you don't like that idea you should go with Brian's idea. :)